# Extending metadata xml without overwriting in org

Tags: managed-package, metadata, xml, second-generation-packaging

I'm creating a 2GP managed packaged that adds a custom tab to the Service Console. While developing in a scratch org, the metadata pulled into my project includes a customised version of the Service Console metadata (including eg. the app's `<label>`, `<formFactor>` etc.) Is there a way I can store only the additional tab metadata and be able to push that to the org without overwriting the org's Service Console metadata?

Essentially, if someone installs my package, I don't want my package metadata overwriting something a customer has already setup themselves.